# Ignore files during parse deploy

Tags: deployment, parse-platform

It would be great to be able to ignore files during the Parse.com deploy process. Possibly using a .parseignore or .deployignore file or something.

This feature has been requested many times with little to no resolution. Here are some links from up to a year ago of folks asking for this feature:

https://www.parse.com/questions/ignore-files-on-deploy

https://www.parse.com/questions/ignore-files-on-deploy--2

https://www.parse.com/questions/is-there-a-way-to-explicitly-ignore-files-with-deploy

http://goo.gl/5JyP3z

Parse dev team, please implement this feature or allow the community to do it!
Thanks

Comment: If you think this should be implemented as part of the Parse Cloud Code CLI, file a bug here parse.com/help. StackOverflow is not the place to post feature requests/bug reports.